# nginx - Trying to push to facebook live

Tags: facebook, nginx, live, rtmp

I try to push stream to facebook from nginx server withi this summary:
- install nginx (with rtmp module) on debian 
- nginx.conf

```
rtmp {
  server{
    listen 9999;
    chunk_size 4096;
    application live {
      live on;
      record off;
      push rtmp://live-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/key;
    }
  }
}
```

and error received:

```
2018/01/23 09:31:10 [error] 6826#0: connect() to [2a03:2880:f002:12a:face:b00c:0:1411]:80 failed (101: Network is unreachable)
2018/01/23 09:31:10 [error] 6826#0: *5 relay: push reconnect failed name='online' app='' playpath='' url='live-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/key', client: IP, server: 0.0.0.0:9999
```

Is there something wrong ?

I'm still in searching to resolve this

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

replace 'key' from your push URL with your private key found in https://www.facebook.com/live/create

Sometime in peak hour, the facebook RTMP server stop accepting new request. Happened to me so many times while simulcast Youtube/FB Live / Twitch on Nginx RTMP Module.

Another solution is, fire up free tier AWS EC2 AMI Linux, install NGINX with RTMP Module and pushing from there.

Comment: Thank @Stream.My, I've found that my Firewall block port 9999 :).  And put right facebook key also